# How can I print the content of PyByteArrayObject*?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I am using [PyArg_Parsetuple](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTuple) to parse a bytearray sent from Python with the `Y` format specifier.

```
Y (bytearray) [PyByteArrayObject *]
Requires that the Python object is a bytearray object, without attempting any conversion.
Raises TypeError if the object is not a bytearray object.
```

In C code I am doing:

```c
static PyObject* py_write(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
       PyByteArrayObject* obj;
       PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "Y", &obj);

.
.
.
```

The Python script is sending the following data:

```python
arr = bytearray()
arr.append(0x2)
arr.append(0x0)
```

---

How do I loop over the PyByteArrayObject* in C? To print 2 and 0?

Comment: Have you looked at the declaration for [`PyByteArrayObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/cpython/bytearrayobject.h)?

Comment: @AKX thanks couldn't find this link. Will hopefully now be able to do so and answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than poking implementation details, you should go through the [documented API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytearray.html), particularly, accessing the data buffer through `PyByteArray_AS_STRING` or `PyByteArray_AsString` rather than through direct struct member access:

```c
char *data = PyByteArray_AS_STRING(bytearray);
Py_ssize_t len = PyByteArray_GET_SIZE(bytearray);

for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    do_whatever_with(data[i]);
}
```

Note that everything in the public API takes the bytearray as a `PyObject *`, not a `PyByteArrayObject *`.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comment section, I found [the definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/cpython/bytearrayobject.h) for PyByteArrayObject

```c
/* Object layout */
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    Py_ssize_t ob_alloc;   /* How many bytes allocated in ob_bytes */
    char *ob_bytes;        /* Physical backing buffer */
    char *ob_start;        /* Logical start inside ob_bytes */
    Py_ssize_t ob_exports; /* How many buffer exports */
} PyByteArrayObject;
```

And the actual code to loop

```c
PyByteArrayObject* obj;
PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "Y", &obj);

Py_ssize_t i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < PyByteArray_GET_SIZE(obj); i++)
    printf("%u\n", obj->ob_bytes[i]);
```

And I got the expected output.

---

Even better, simply use the [Direct API](http://PyByteArray_AsString)

```c
char* s = PyByteArray_AsString(obj);
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < PyByteArray_GET_SIZE(obj); i++)
    printf("%u\n", s[i]);
```

Comment: You're poking implementation details there - the struct layout is not part of the public API.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica how can I then in C print the data passed from python bytearray?